# Can Error Prone Auto-Apply Suggested Fixes?

Tags: java, command-line, lint, errorprone

From what I read about Error Prone, I see that it will actually suggest fixes for style errors in your code.  i.e from https://errorprone.info/docs/installation:

```
ERROR: example/myproject/BUILD:29:1: Java compilation in rule '//example/myproject:hello'
examples/maven/error_prone_should_flag/src/main/java/Main.java:20: error: [DeadException] Exception created but not thrown
    new Exception();
    ^
    (see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/DeadException)
  Did you mean 'throw new Exception();'?
1 error
```

What I do not see, is if there is a way to auto-apply these suggested changes.  I am running error-prone from the command line.  Any and all help is appreciated!  Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a way to auto-apply them directly.

However, you can get Error Prone to spit out a patch file containing the fixes. Refer to the [patching documentation](http://errorprone.info/docs/patching):

> To apply the suggested fixes for checks built in to the Error Prone compiler, you’ll add two compiler flags to your compiler invocation:
>
> ```
> -XepPatchChecks:MissingOverride,DefaultCharset,DeadException
> -XepPatchLocation:/full/path/to/your/source/root
> ```
>
> ...
>
> You can inspect the patch file directly, and apply it to your source with:
>
> ```
> cd /full/path/to/your/source/root
> patch -p0 -u -i error-prone.patch
> ```

(Note the disclaimer about this being experimental)

Answer (score 2):

While not current [documented](http://errorprone.info/docs/patching), it *is* possible to directly apply the suggested changes to the affected source code. One does this by passing `-XepPatchLocation:IN_PLACE`:

Modifying the original example, the invocation then becomes:

```
-XepPatchChecks:MissingOverride,DefaultCharset,DeadException
-XepPatchLocation:IN_PLACE
```

It is strongly recommended to use this feature only when the original file is managed by a version control system. The result can then easily be inspected using e.g. `git diff` and reverted using e.g. `git checkout -- .`.